# Compare multiple text criteria to text field in single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of multiple text criteria that I need to use to count occurrences of matching text in the database with the LIKE operator.

How can I write a query that will run the comparison with all criteria at once and return a summarized list of counts per each of these criteria?

I've started with a simple query on which I'd like to iterate using a while loop. But unfortunately, I don't have the right to create a table that would contain the criteria to be referenced with each loop so I have to prepare query for each criteria separately.

```
SELECT sum(X), sum(Y), Z
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE 'criteria sample'
WHERE A = nnnnnn
AND B > 0
Group by Z
```

To avoid running and writing multiple queries, how can I load all criteria into one query to run them against the content to get the results faster out?

Comment: look up window functions and see if that helps.  Different criteria in the select statement using partitions.  It's a bit over my head but it just might do what you want.  Or maybe a bunch of case statements sum(case when text like 'criteria1' then X), sum(case when) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a table in the query with your values:

```
SELECT v.comparison, sum(t.X), sum(t.Y), t.Z
FROM table t JOIN
     (VALUES ('criteria sample'),
             ('criteria sample 2'),
             . . .   -- whatever the values are
     ) v(comparison)
     ON t.text LIKE v.comparison
WHERE t.A = nnnnnn AND t.B > 0
GROUP BY v.comparison, t.Z;
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like exactly what I need, I was wondering how can I construct a table in the query but couldn't find info online.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted every matching row, you could simply say `WHERE text LIKE '%foo%' OR text LIKE '%bar%'`. However, if I understand your question, you actually want a count of rows matching `'%foo%'` and a separate count of rows matching `'%bar%'`. This implies that the `SUM`s and `GROUP BY` have to be run separately for each criteria text.

One possible solution is to write all the queries separately, then `union` them at the end. Note that `union` requires every column to have a name.  You'll also want a static identifier string in each subquery so you can tell which criteria was met. So you'll have something like:

```
SELECT sum(X) AS sumx, sum(Y) AS sumy, Z, 'foo' AS criteria FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%foo%' AND A = nnnnnn AND B > 0 Group by Z
UNION
SELECT sum(X) AS sumx, sum(Y) AS sumy, Z, 'bar' AS criteria FROM table WHERE text LIKE '%bar%' AND A = nnnnnn AND B > 0 Group by Z
UNION
...(etc)...
```

Comment: This actually helps to display results, but still requires manual input of all criteria, I, unfortunately, have 86 of them at this moment.
I will try this and invest a little bit of manual work. it's one-time thing anyway.
Thanks!

Comment: What format do you have the criteria in? If they're in a spreadsheet, you can use a spreadsheet formula to generate the text of the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should just work like this, if I'm understanding correctly.

```
select t.z,
   sum(case when text like '%firstcriteria%' then 1 else 0 end) as countfirstcriteria,
   sum(case when text like '%secondcriteria%' then 1 else 0 end) as countsecondcriteria
from table t
where A = 'nnnnnn'
   AND B > 0
group by t.z
```

Answer (score 0):

Like should follow with % symbol so that the word you are looking for is captured even if there a words before or after it. I also removed the redundant `WHERE`

```
SELECT sum(X), sum(Y), Z
FROM table
WHERE text LIKE '%criteria sample%'
AND A = 'nnnnnn'
AND B > 0
Group by Z
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed putting that. However, my question doesn't focus on the syntax of this query, but rather on what kind of query I need to write to be able to run multiple comparisons at once and get the summarized number of matches per each criteria separately (I have multiple criteria)